# compare two form's check box checked or not

Tags: php, javascript, forms, checkbox

I have two or more form. and each form contain some check box and the check value shown in a text box. I want that when I chek some check box total value will shown in a text box in that form. **I want that when I check some check box of one form other form's check box will not checked and return a alert**.
here is my code:

```
<head>
<script>function UpdateCost() {
  var sum = 0;
  var gn, elem;
  for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    gn = 'budget'+i;
    elem = document.getElementById(gn);
    if (elem.checked == true) { sum += Number(elem.value); }
  }
  document.getElementById('totalcost').value = sum.toFixed(2);
} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
// 1st form
<form name= "form1">
<input type="checkbox" id='budget0' value="9.99"  onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 1 ( 9.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget1' value="19.99" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 2 (19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget2' value="27.50" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 3 (27.50)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget3' value="45.65" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 4 (45.65)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget4' value="87.20" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 5 (87.20)<br>
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="">// total budget
</form>
// 2nd form
<form name= "form2">
<input type="checkbox" id='budget0' value="9.99"  onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 1 ( 9.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget1' value="19.99" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 2 (19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget2' value="27.50" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 3 (27.50)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget3' value="45.65" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 4 (45.65)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='budget4' value="87.20" onclick="UpdateCost()">Game 5 (87.20)<br>
<input type="text" id="totalcost" value="">// total budget
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Do i need to clarify anything or does my new code satisfy the question?

Answer (score 2):

Fistr of all - ID has to be unique - you cannot add two elements with the same id.

Change them to `name="budget[0]"` and so on. The same thing with `totalcost` -> `name="totalcost"`.

Then modify your function to:

```
function UpdateCost(input) {
    var elements = input.form.elements;
    var sum = 0;
    var resultElement;

    for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
        var element = elements[i];
        if ( element.type == 'checkbox' && element.checked ) {
            sum += parseFloat( element.value );
        } else if ( element.type == 'text' ) {
            resultElement = element;
        }
    }

    element.value = sum;
}
```

And now change `onclick` events to `onclick="UpdateCost(this)"`

Comment: I want that when I check a check box of one form then check box of another form will not check and also value of checkbox will be added and shown in respective text box.

Comment: @Moumita - I do not know if I understand you at all.. If checkbox nr 3 will be checked in form 1 then it should be unchecked in form 2 and in all forms `totalcost` should be updated ?

Comment: no. this two form is totally different and contain different value and I have more than two form. I want that no one can check checkbox from two different form together. and when I check a check box of one form then value of checkbox will be added and shown in a respective text box. and samething will happen for other forms.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JQuery or Prototype Javascript libraries. They were built for doing such things and should make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all id's need to be **unique** so for example add the form to the id.

Moreover tell the UpdateCost function what form you are working on, by adding a **parameter**

Than you will already modify the correct total field, and the total will be calculated for each form you have.

```
<head>
<script>

    var only_allowed_for = '';

    function UpdateCost(form) {
        if (only_allowed_for == '') {

            only_allowed_for = form;

        }

        var sum = 0;
        var gn, elem;
        for (i=0; i<5; i++) {

            gn = form + '_budget'+ i;
            elem = document.getElementById(gn);

            if (elem.checked == true)
                if (only_allowed_for == form) {
                    sum += Number(elem.value);
                } else {

                    elem.checked = false;

                }

          }
          document.getElementById(form + '_totalcost').value = sum.toFixed(2);
    } 
</script>
</head>

<body>
// 1st form
<form name= "form1">
<input type="checkbox" id='form1_budget0' value="9.99"  onclick="UpdateCost('form1')">Game 1 ( 9.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form1_budget1' value="19.99" onclick="UpdateCost('form1')">Game 2 (19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form1_budget2' value="27.50" onclick="UpdateCost('form1')">Game 3 (27.50)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form1_budget3' value="45.65" onclick="UpdateCost('form1')">Game 4 (45.65)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form1_budget4' value="87.20" onclick="UpdateCost('form1')">Game 5 (87.20)<br>
<input type="text" id="form1_totalcost" value="0.00">// total budget
</form>
// 2nd form
<form name= "form2">
<input type="checkbox" id='form2_budget0' value="9.99"  onclick="UpdateCost('form2')">Game 1 ( 9.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form2_budget1' value="19.99" onclick="UpdateCost('form2')">Game 2 (19.99)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form2_budget2' value="27.50" onclick="UpdateCost('form2')">Game 3 (27.50)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form2_budget3' value="45.65" onclick="UpdateCost('form2')">Game 4 (45.65)<br>
<input type="checkbox" id='form2_budget4' value="87.20" onclick="UpdateCost('form2')">Game 5 (87.20)<br>
<input type="text" id="form2_totalcost" value="0.00">// total budget
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: its add checkbox value. but I also need that when someone check some checkbox of form1 he/she can't check checkbox of form2.please help me.

Comment: @Moumita I edited my post, but i don't have much time so it's not clean code, but i think it now pretty much does what you asked for.